# Combine two differently sized lists into a combined set

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I'm trying to combine 2 lists that have different data and size into 1, and have the smaller list "wrap" around. I'm looking for a clean way to do this, e.g.

Input:

```
list1 = ['apple', 'orange', 'strawberry', 'avocado']
list2 = ['1','2','3']
```

Output:

```
[ 
    {"l1": "apple", "l2": "1"}, 
    {"l1": "orange", "l2": "2"}, 
    {"l1": "strawberry", "l2": "3"}, 
    {"l1": "avocado", "l2": "1"}
 ]
```

Notice that for `"avocado"`, we went back to `"1"` and wrapped around list2.

The obvious (and ugly looking) solution is to just start with an empty list, have 2 indexes in a loop, each iteration append a new list item, and the smaller one 'wraps' to the beginning when it reaches the end. Is there a clean way of doing this in Python 2.7?

Comment: Consider `itertools.izip` along `itertools.cycle` on your shorter list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to wrap the second list:

```
from itertools import cycle

lst = [dict(zip(['l1', 'l2'], tup)) for tup in zip(list1, cycle(list2))]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a generator that avoids appending to an empty list:

```
def func(l1, l2):
    length1 = len(l1)
    length2 = len(l2)
    for idx in range(max(length1, length2)):
        # I use the modulo so the indices wrap around.
        yield {'l1': l1[idx % length1], 'l2': l2[idx % length2]}

list(func(list1, list2))
# [{'l1': 'apple', 'l2': '1'},
#  {'l1': 'orange', 'l2': '2'},
#  {'l1': 'strawberry', 'l2': '3'},
#  {'l1': 'avocado', 'l2': '1'}]
```

However `itertools.cycle` (see the other answer) is probably much better.

Answer (score 2):

You can merely use `enumerate` for simplicity; however, a cleaner solution would involve `itertools.cycle`:

```
list1 = ['apple', 'orange', 'strawberry', 'avocado']
list2 = ['1','2','3']
new_list = [{"li":a, "l2":list2[i%len(list2)]} for i, a in enumerate(list1)]
```

Output:

```
[{'l2': '1', 'li': 'apple'}, {'l2': '2', 'li': 'orange'}, {'l2': '3', 'li': 'strawberry'}, {'l2': '1', 'li': 'avocado'}]
```

Comment: Apologies.  I just noticed that our answers are the same and that yours came earlier.  Add the timings to yours, and I'll delete mine.

Comment: @Alexander No problem at all! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
def processing(opt, longlist, shortlist):
  def processing_iter(inL, refL, outL):
    if refL == []:
      return outL
    elif inL == []:
      return processing_iter(shortlist, refL[1:], outL+opt(refL[0], shortlist[0]))
    else:
      return processing_iter(inL[1:], refL[1:], outL+opt(refL[0], inL[0]))
  return processing_iter(shortlist, longlist, [])


def makedict(a,b): return [{"l1":a, "l2":b}]

list1 = ['apple', 'orange', 'strawberry', 'avocado']
list2 = ['1','2','3']
print(processing(makedict,list1, list2))
```